# "Listening" for changes in cookie in all opened tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, cookies, tabs

So, I have this cookie that affect my login state in an app. When I erase it the user will logout, in login it will be created (all happens in server side, and is sent to me). Simple enough.

Question is - Is there any way to affect the user in tab A, if he got another tab B which is a duplicate of A?

e.g. The user login in tab A, duplicate the tab to tab B, logs out from there then returns to tab A - and he logged out there as well.

Just to be clear - I'm asking if this is possible browser-wise in JavaScript.

Comment: There is no event mechanism to listen to cookie changes. You could use [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate across windows. Where and how you use it would depend on your logout process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the cookie when the user focus the tab.

> window.onfocus